# Test if value is in array with underscoreJS using _.some method

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
let array = [1234, 1233, 1232];

console.log(_.some(array, 1234));
```

It returns `false`. Do you know why?

Comment: `console.log(_.some(array, function(v){ return v === 1234}));`

Comment: Ok fine thanks! Do you maybe know a simpler method to test if a value is in array with underscore?

Comment: in this case you can simple use `indexOf()`

Comment: You could also use [`_.contains`](http://underscorejs.org/#contains) e.g `_.contains(array, 1234)`

Comment: Yes, I know why, because I read the documentation for `_.some`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation of `_.some()` method](http://underscorejs.org/#some), second argument should be a predicate function

```
console.log(_.some(array, function(v){ return v === 1234}));
```

---

In this particular case you can simply use native javascript **[`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** method.

```
console.log(array.indexOf(1234) > -1);
```

---

Also there is native JavaScript **[`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** method.

```
console.log(array.some(function(v){ return v === 1234}));
```

with [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
console.log(array.some(v => v == 1234))
```

Comment: There is also ES5 *some* and ECMAScript 2015 arrow functions to give: `array.some(v=>v==1234)`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With UNDERSCORE.JS you can simply use,

```
console.log(_.indexOf(array, 1234) >= 0)
```

Document for more details:
http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf